# How to remove key array in javascript by keep default value

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to delete key in array

here is my array

```
const data = [ { id: "2" } , { id: "4" } ]
```

I want ouput

```
['2','4']
```

here is what i try

```
  data.map(function(item) {
     //I return only item.id but output still not change 
    return item.id
  })
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Comment: you need to store the result of `.map()` in a variable

Comment: ```data``` variable is not changed by ```map```. Put this into another variable. ```const res = data.map(item => item.id)```

Comment: Array.prototype.map returns a new array, it doesnt modify the existing array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method returns a new array, it does not alternate the current array. You need to store the returned array in another variable to get the required output like:

```js
const data = [ { id: "2" } , { id: "4" } ] 
const res = data.map(x => x.id)
console.log( res )
```

Or, using same variable:

```js
let data = [ { id: "2" } , { id: "4" } ] 
data = data.map(x => x.id)
console.log( data )
```

Comment: OH i see is their anyway to store at the same variable

Comment: Yes, you can simply do `data = data.map(x => x.id)`, but you will need to change `data` from const to let, as we can not modify a const variable for obvious reason.

Answer (score -1):

Map returns new array and do not alter source array. so you need to assign the result to a new variable.

```js
const data = [{
  id: "2"
}, {
  id: "4"
}];

const output = data.map(function(item) {
  return item.id
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? We map the key to a number and return it.

```
const data = [ { id: "2" } , { id: "4" } ];
var result = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) { 
  return Number(key); 
}); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: yep but is their anyway to store at variable data

Comment: var result1 = result[0]; // 2